# I want to downvote twice

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, downvotes

There are some questions or answers that are so stupid, thoughtless, or inane, that I want to downvote them twice, even if the second downvote costs 10 points. Has such a thing ever been proposed?

Comment: I was going to say, "ridiculous", until I saw, "even if the second downvote costs 10 points".  Interesting proposal.

Comment: I think that one downvote is enough...the point of voting isn't to punish the user, but to sort out good/bad content.

Comment: I think it would make reputation too important.  It's almost like saying that those with more money get more votes _directly_ in an election.  Not very community-orientied.

Comment: What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Honestly, the first downvote is often already enough to rile up almost anybody, regardless of whether or not others pile on afterward. If the post really is that bad, pile-on votes almost certainly will follow.

Comment: Would you revert/refund the extra rep cost if the post is deleted?  Or is it actually like a "wanted dead" bounty with no refund? Can I put out a hit on an answer (it's self-defense I swear)?

Comment: Why stop at twice? Make downvotes unlimited on a given post, but the cost exponential. -1, -10, -100, -1000...

Comment: @JoshCaswell I can't wait for you to walk away from your computer for a minute so I can use your account to downvote an arbitrary question into oblivion.

Comment: people would purposely spam downvotes on random questions

Comment: And the third costs 100, the fourth 1000, and the fifth 10000. If you want to sacrifice three years of work, here's the site for you!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While sportsmanship is encouraged, some users do not really abide by that.

As reputation increases, the ability to leverage downvotes on competing answers would carry less consequence, and as a result users who may not be the best sports would have a rather large advantage, and would also slightly ruin the experience for competing answers.

Furthermore, this essentially gives higher reputation users a weighted representation of the community. For example, a high reputation user posts, as do 2 lower reputation users. The higher reputation user's post starts at +0, the other 2 at -3. This would at first glance seem to be the community responding to the competing answers whereas it was really one user who would also be biased.

If you see an answer that is incorrect, just downvote it and move on (re: "someone is wrong on the internet!"). If you see an answer which is dangerous, perhaps leave a comment. And if you see an answer which is not an answer (spam, add on question, comment, gibberish) then flag it.

tldr;

I don't think this would be beneficial as it would allow higher reputation users to have a weighted representation of the community.

Comment: But it would let me combat pity upvotes!

Comment: `"I don't think this would be beneficial as it would allow higher reputation users to have a weighted representation of the community."` -- We're all equal, but some are more equal than others. (joking!)

Answer (score 8):

You sorta have a second downvote on questions already.

Flag it [VLQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous/93606#93606) and if reviewers confirm your assessment by closing the question, yet another vote down from [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1) user will be [added automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215328/165773).

Comment: disappointing update for those hoping to (ab)use this feature: since June 2018 [closing a question with active VLQ flag doesn't trigger an automatic Community downvote anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310974/165773)

Comment: but flagging as spam or rude does. And flagging an answer (more than a question) as VLQ often leads to deletion and/or downvotes if the content is bad