# What restrictions (the red box stops the submission) are there for question content?

Tags: discussion

I wouldn't have known that SO allowed a lot more code in questions in the past if I hadn't run into an issue with editing old posts and wondered why. I know of a few more things like this but I want a more comprehensive list.

What restrictions  were added to posts questions? Can I get an estimate of when these restrictions were added?

Comment: List questions became off topic about 7 years ago.

Comment: It should be possible to award more downvotes on long code dumps.  One extra downvote per page would be good.

Comment: @MartinJames [you want to downvote twice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288852/839601)? :)

Answer (score 14):

There's a ratio check in place, which will block questions if the amount of code exceeds the amount of non-code by some generous amount.

The intent here is to encourage people to include some explanation with their code, something beyond "fix this".

Folks mostly ignore it, but they can't say we didn't warn them.